# Symfony lowest user bid using MIN function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to get the lowest bid of the user for each product id.

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT PARTIAL b.{Id, MIN(amount) as amount, currency}, PARTIAL p.{id, firstName, lastName}
            FROM  AppBundle:Bid b
            LEFT JOIN b.provider p
            WHERE b.product in (:product)
            AND b.status = :status
            GROUP BY b.product
            ORDER BY b.amount'
        )
        ->setParameter('product', $ids)
        ->setParameter('status', 'active')
        ->getResult()
    ;
```

I get following error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 42: Error: Expected
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_CURLY_BRACE, got '('

I have run exactly similar query in SQL, it works fine, but I'm not sure how to achieve same in doctrine query builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want user mysql function with doctrine query you must be add extension of doctrine mysql function OR you can user native query. I have added native query in follow:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;


$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('AppBundle:Bid', 'b');
$rsm->addFieldResult('b', 'Id', 'Id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('b', 'amount', 'amount');
$rsm->addFieldResult('b', 'currency', 'currency');
...
$sqlQuery = "SELECT b.Id, MIN(b.amount), b.currency, p.firstName, p.lastName
        FROM  AppBundle:Bid b
        LEFT JOIN b.AppBundle:Provider p
        WHERE b.AppBundle:Product in (:product)
        AND b.status = :status
        GROUP BY b.product
        ORDER BY b.amount";
$query = $em->createNativeQuery($sqlQuery, $rsm)
     ->setParameter('product', $ids)
     ->setParameter('status', 'active');
$query->getResult();
```

Please let me know if any problem with this one

Comment: Its not working and giving lots of errror. Maybe partial is not allowed on native query? I have tried removing that, but then I get error on join

Comment: Hi Basit, I have edit query.. please try this one.. if not work then please give me table details... thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

When using the `PARTIAL` keyword in your DQL query, you can only list properties of the entities you select from (the `MIN()` function is no property of your entity). You can simply leave out the `PARTIAL` part and use a query like this (please note that Doctrine will not return objects in your result set but only a flat array, see also http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax):

```
SELECT b.Id, MIN(b.amount) as amount, b.currency as bid, p.id, p.firstName, p.lastName as provider
FROM  AppBundle:Bid b
LEFT JOIN b.provider p
WHERE b.product in (:product) AND b.status = :status
GROUP BY b.product
ORDER BY b.amount
```

Comment: amount is property of entity, setting MIN(b.amount) as amount would still not work?  Is there a way of converting array into objects? I need to use objects (some of functions in codebase asks for objects)